# How to give a item that cannot be dropped on death

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I know for a fact that there is a way to /give players an item that cannot be crafted with, or dropped on death. I have seen things on how to do this but they are hard to understand. Can someone give me a example of a command to /give like a dirt block or smth were it won't drop on death?

Comment: For tools and armour, "Curse of vanishing" works. Would be worth a try if it works for any item.